# While using data validation on a excel Column i am getting error The Formula evaluates to an Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula i am using is:"=$E19=VLOOKUP($E19,FundsLists,1,FALSE)"
where FundsLists IS a list

Comment: Perhaps FundsLIsts is oriented horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You've given very little information, but did you mean to use
`=IF($E19=VLOOKUP($E19,FundsLists,1,FALSE),TRUE,FALSE)` ?